# Fail to retrieve datasource via JNDI, Tomcat 7, Intellij Idea

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, jndi

I have a project which starts in Eclipse. I want to start it in Intellij Idea and I faced a problem with JNDI lookup. So, what I have:
In CATALINA_HOME\conf\server.xml I declared some resource:

```
<Server>
  ...
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="quartzDS" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          username="username"
          password="password"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quartz_test?...
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          initialSize="5"
          maxWait="5000"
          maxActive="120"
          maxIdle="5"
          validationQuery="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"
          poolPreparedStatements="true"/>
  </GlobalNamingResources>
 ...
</Server>
```

My project has multiple modules, some of them are packed in wars. So, I'm trying to deploy them using tomcat 7.0.7 through Intellij Idea. I created Run Configuration for it, specified all artifacts with context pathes and tried to run. Modules which need global resource has webapp\META-INF\context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/foo/bar" crossContext="true">
    <ResourceLink name="quartzDS" global="quartzDS"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
</Context>
```

Each module has it's own context.xml. 
But when I'm trying to run this Tomcat configuration I see such exception in each war:

```
ERROR (org.quartz.utils.JNDIConnectionProvider) Error looking up datasource: Name [quartzDS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [quartzDS].
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [quartzDS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [quartzDS].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:819)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:830)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:830)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:167)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:156)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at org.quartz.utils.JNDIConnectionProvider.init(JNDIConnectionProvider.java:124)
    at org.quartz.utils.JNDIConnectionProvider.<init>(JNDIConnectionProvider.java:102)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate(StdSchedulerFactory.java:993)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.getScheduler(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1519)
    at org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener.contextInitialized(QuartzInitializerListener.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5099)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5615)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1863)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here my quartz scheduler properties:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck = true
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = Some Scheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.jobFactory.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleJobFactory
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 5
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate

org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = quartzDS
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = false
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDS.jndiURL=java:/comp/env/quartzDS
```

Such property file is in classpath for each module.
Can anybody help me to fix my configuration?